Expansion of trace of operator
I am looking for a way to rewrite this trace "at leading order in $a$"
$$
\text{Tr}(-a\nabla^2+A(r))
$$
Would it be possible to expand this trace if my parameter $a$ is small, $a<<1$ (which is the case), at the leading order, I can assume $A$ is constant and obtain maybe powers of $A$. Should I rewrite the trace as a sum over eigenstates?
Or is it already a known problem?
My function $A(r)$ is $A(r)=\lambda(r)-\mu(r)$ but I don't think it will matter at first approximation.

I think I'm missing something. Isn't the trace a linear opeartion? So I would expect $\text{Tr}(-a\nabla^2+A(r)) = -a\text{Tr}(\nabla^2) + \text{Tr}(A(r))$

This of this as a perturbation theory problem.  You go to a basis where $A(r)$ is diagonal, and thus you get $\sum_i A_{ii}+a\langle \nabla^2\rangle_{ii}$ where the average values are obtained using your set of eigenfunctions of $A(r)$.

Those operators are not trace class. Therefore the trace must be regularised (for instance using the $\zeta$ function procedure). These procedures may break linearity. Hence the answer is not obvious.

what do you mean by "trace class"? but I see, I should use $\zeta_O(s)=Tr( \mid O \mid ^{-s})$? and found this zeta function for $s=-1$
